# Jekyll will only build with "jekyll update" category

Tags: jekyll

This is my first time using Jekyll and its all been going very well so far. I'm sure I am missing something or doing something silly but when I try and change a posts categories to something other than "jekyll update" the site breaks completely.

I have tried specifying the categories in many different front matter formats but even if I change:

```
categories: jekyll update
```

to:

```
categories: test
```

It breaks and I have no idea why.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but I've moved the categories key under title instead of at the bottom of the front matter block and it is now working.